# R to PostgreSQL integer converted into scientific notion

Tags: r, postgresql

I am facing an issue while writing integer64 to PostgreSQL, its getting converted into scientific notion number.
I am using windows 64bit OS and and R 3.5 version 
and another system of 64bit ubunto with R 3.3
When writing sometimes its giving scientific notion some time its writes well but 90% of times i am getting such issue.
for example  99999679872  written as 1.9277322e-315.

looking for some alternative library or something that can help.

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: 99999679872 is too big for `integer`. Have you tried using `bigint`?

Comment: see also: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html